# Rails 3.1: Output current data from will_paginate to PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, prawn

I've been working with rails for a few weeks now, whenever I had time. I'm trying to create a PDF output of the currently shown data of my application. I'm using prawn, which is working fine and will_paginate. Is it possible to send the current data, which is shown on the screen (e.g. the selected page), to the pdf output?

`index.html.erb`:

```
<% @truckdeliveries.each do |truckdelivery| %>
 ...
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @truckdeliveries %>
<%= link_to "PDF", truckdeliveries_path(@truckdelivery ,format: "pdf") %>
```

`truckdeliveries_controller.rb`:

```
class TruckdeliveriesController < ApplicationController

def index
  @truckdeliveries = Truckdelivery.paginate page: params[:page], order: 'created_at desc',
  per_page: 10

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @truckdeliveries }
    format.pdf do
      pdf = TruckdeliveryPdf.new(@truckdeliveries)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: "truckdelivery_.pdf",
                                    type: "application/pdf"
    end
  end
end
...
```

This is working fine, but it only shows the data for the first page and doesn't change if I switch to another page. I tried changing the link_to to @truckdeliveries but that only creates one cryptic link.

I tried google but I'm still having trouble using the right buzz words. So any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me the reason that it is only printing the first page is because your PDF link isn't including the page parameter. Try this instead.

```
<%= link_to "PDF", truckdeliveries_path(:format => "pdf", :page => params[:page]) %>
```

Comment: Hi, ty very much. That did the trick!! I had tried that before but of course put that part not in the parenthesis. I had to alter the 'truckdeliveries_controller.rb' a little and added for the pdf the line '@truckdeliveries = truckdelivery.limit(10).offset(params[:offset].to_i).order("created_at desc")' bcause the paginated variable didn't seem to deliver the correct values.